# Magento 2 AJAX Post to another module's controller

Tags: magento2, php, ajax

I was wondering if it were possible to send an AJAX Post over to a controller contained within a custom module I have created. The reason for doing this is because I want to separate my logic out from the module-sales module.

Alternatively, would it be possible to contain the controller within Magento_Sales as currently my folder structure for this just contains overridden frontend files such as layout / template etc. Any help appreciated on this, cheers

Comment: I'd use the webapi instead of a controller

Comment: How would I go about using the webapi?

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-api/

Comment: I'll give it a whirl, cheers for the help

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a controller and return a Json from it that you can process on success.

An example :

JS file

```
 var responseajax = $.ajax({
                    url: action,
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json'
                });
```

Note that you can build an url with the urlBuilder :

Include the urlbuilder like this :

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'mage/url',
    ],
    function ($, url) {
... 
                var url= url.build('path/to/controller');
...
```

Your controller will need to return a json

```
....
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory,
        Data $jsonHelper,
    )
    {
....
        $this->_jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
        $this->_jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        parent::__construct(
            $context
        );
    }

public function execute(){
$arraydata = your array data
        return $this->_jsonFactory->create()->setJsonData($this->_jsonHelper->jsonEncode($arraydata ));

}
```

And after that just process the data with your JS

```
...
responseajax.success(function (response) {
...
response is your json array or Object
....
}
...
```

**This answer is based on the fact that you know how to create a basic route and controller.**